# why aren't values of my map <int, <object>> inserting correctly?

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

I am using maps in a project and I realize values are not inserting correctly in my maps, so I did the following debugging code, which still shows the problem.

```
class Point2
{
    private:
        double _coordinates[2];
        int _label = -2;
   public:
        Point2(const double x = 0.0, const double y = 0.0){_coordinates[0]=x;_coordinates[1]=y;}
        int getPointLabel() const{ return _label;}
        void setPointLabel(const int label){_label =label;}

};
main(){

     Point2 p1(11,22);
     Point2 p2(33,66);
     p1.setPointLabel(50);
     p2.setPointLabel(90);
     map<int,Point2> testmap;
     testmap.insert(pair<int, Point2>(100,p1));
     testmap.insert(pair<int, Point2>(200,p2));
     

     map<int,Point2>::iterator iter;
     for(iter = testmap.begin(); iter != testmap.end(); iter++)
     {
         cout << (*iter).first <<"...";
         cout << (*iter).second.getFirstCoordinate()<<"...";
         cout << (*iter).second.getSecondCoordinate()<<"...";
         cout << (*iter).second.getPointLabel()<<endl;
     }

     map<int,Point2*> testmap2;
     testmap2.insert(pair<int, Point2*>(100,&p1));
     testmap2.insert(pair<int, Point2*>(200,&p2));

     map<int,Point2> testmap3;
     testmap3.insert({100, p1});
     testmap3.insert({200, p2});
     cout <<"the end"<<endl;


}
```

The debbugger is showing this values for testmap, right at the last line:
[image]

[image]

[image]

In my original project instead of member _coordinates being an array of integers, it is a vector2d object from an external numerical linear algebra  library called Eigen, and the problem was similar, but at least one the values of the inserted elements into the map ( the ordinates of the vector2d objectS ) were set to the abcissas of the inserted Points. Solving this problem may help me realize why they are not setting correctly in my project, too.

Why aren't elements inserting correctly into testmap?

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us. And please tell us exactly when and where you break the program so you can look at the map.

Comment: can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/rjrjcznnq. Are you running a debug build? The variable inspectors are not to be trusted in release/optimised builds

Comment: When you say `right after the second line` is this before the line declaring `testmap`? At that point `testmap` is probably uninitialised and has indeterminate values

Comment: [Looks fine](https://godbolt.org/z/nWqvhdbrM) on godbolt.

Comment: @AlanBirtles not sure what you mean with that. I am using qtcreator I added this class in some class file and the code I placed here in the main, is actually running from   a testfile that is intended to be used with google tests. My actual main only calls for running google tests

Comment: @AlanBirtles sorry i meant the last line, after the two insertions

Comment: With the code shown the last line is the end of the function and the objects might have gone out of scope, their life-time ended, and been destructed. So you're then looking at invalid data.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I added another line at the end just to put the break point there and the result is the same. Also going step by step  shows that the content of the map don't change at any time. They are added with those values

Comment: Definitely sounds like you're using a release build and your map isn't used anywhere so is simply optimised out. Have you tried printing the values like in the two examples we've given?

Comment: I am using a debug built

Comment: I guess you are actually inserting temporaries with your inserts. Try inserting with initializer list (C++11) `testmap.insert({100, p1});` instead.

Comment: @Chilippso  not working and the first elements gets set to zero as in the picture

Comment: I don't know if any of it will help, but please try also using [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) and [`std::make_pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair), in different combinations (and `make_pair` together with `insert`). You don't have to show the debugger information for all the attempts, just say if it worked or not.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Is there by any chance you are using a custom copy constructor, that you have not shown in the example posted here. Other than that anything else does not make sense, since the default copy constructor would do a member wise copy and should reflect the values rather than garbage what you show in the debugger. Also can you try printing those values as well?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude   I used emplace and make_pair in all combinations but it didn't worked

Comment: In an earlier comment you state `"...the code I placed here in the main, is actually running from a testfile that is intended to be used with google tests"`.  Is it possible that the test environment is what's causing the problem?  Other than that the only way I can reproduce the results seen with the given code is, as suggested by @GauravSehgal , to supply a noop copy ctor such as `Point2(const Point2 &){}` .

Comment: @GauravSehgal No, I am only using what is shown here

Comment: @G.M. I am running the code inside main above from  my main directly now just to discard that, but the behavior is the same

Comment: Have you tried printing the values rather than viewing them in the debugger, it's highly likely the variable inspector is simply incorrect

Comment: @AlanBirtles  indeed the values are printing correctly. Then the debugger can't be trust? How can I use it to debug more complicated code then?

Comment: When using pointers like in testmap2, the debugger shows the values correctly, though

Comment: difficult to know without more details about your environment but presumably your debugger simply isn't compatible with your standard library.